# display routes and it's sub routes as a list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Suppose I have these route definition in `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(
            array (
                'prefix' => 'admin'
            ),
            function () {

                        Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
                            Route::get('usersData', ['as' => 'usersData', 'uses' => 'UserController@usersData']);
                            Route::get('getOrgLevelAsJson/{user_id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@getOrgLevelAsJson']);
                        });
                        Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');

                        Route::group(['prefix' => 'role'], function () {
                            Route::get('rolesData', ['as' => 'rolesData', 'uses' => 'RoleController@rolesData']);
                            Route::post('applyPerms', ['as' => 'applyPerms', 'uses' => 'RoleController@applyPerms']);
                        });
                        Route::resource('/role', 'RoleController');

                    }
                );
            }
        );
```

And now for some reason I want to display these routes and it's sub routes as an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>admin/user
        <ul>
            <li>usersData</li>
            <li>getOrgLevelAsJson/{user_id}</li>
            <li>create</li>
            <li>user/{user}</li>
            <li>{user}/edit</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>admin/role
        <ul>
            <li>applyPerms</li>
            <li>rolesData</li>
            <li>create</li>
            <li>role/{role}</li>
            <li>role/{role}/edit</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know that can use `Route::getRoutes()` to get all defined routes but I do not know how can get a route then sub routes of that.

I am using Laravel 5.2 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
$mainRoutes = [];
$allRoutes = [];
foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    array_push($allRoutes, $value->getPath());
    $url = explode('/', $value->getPath());
    if (!in_array($url[0], $mainRoutes)) {
        array_push($mainRoutes, $url[0]);
    }
}
?>
<ul>
    @foreach($mainRoutes as $main_route)
        <li>
            {{$main_route}}
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($allRoutes as $route) {
                $url = explode('/', $route);
                if($main_route == $url[0]){
                ?>
                <li>{{url($route)}}</li>
                <?php
                }
                }
                ?>

            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```